# Git: switching between remote branches

Tags: git, branch

Let's say I have two local branches `a` and `b` and corresponding remotes `A` and `B`. `a` and `b` are the same. Then someone makes a commit to `A`, which changes `file1`. I do `git pull` while at branch `a` and now my `a` is up to date. All good.

Now I wan't to switch to branch `b` to do some work there, so I run `git checkout b`. What happens is that `file1` now shows as unstaged modified file, since it was updated by running `git pull` on branch `a`. Should't branch `b` be unaffected by this? Why is it not the same as `B`, even though I didn't make any modifications to it locally?

Comment: When you are in your branch ````a```` and do a ````git pull```` if do a ````git status````, it shows that everything is up-to-date?

Comment: Yes that's what happens.

Comment: This is definitely not what should happen (unless I misunderstood your question). Please post the output of `git status` after `git pull`

Comment: That's right it was my error! Thanks.